# Appending Rows to Nested HTML Table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a nested Html table, the inner table is hidden. When user clicks a row, the inner row is expanded(accordion) with table. The rows are dynamically generated including the row with inner table using jquery. The problem is when I try to append the rows to last row of tbody of outer html table, the outer table rows that are, after the inner table, are also appended to the inner table row. 
Please let me know where I'm wrong.

```js
function LoadTestTable() {
  var row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 1.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody:last').append(row);

  row = "<tr id='package1' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#OrderPackages' data-target='.packageDetails1'>";
  row += "<td> 2.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.4 </td>";

  row += "</tr>"
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody:last').append(row);

  var nestedrow = "<tr><td colspan='4' class='hiddenRow'><div class='accordion-body collapse packageDetails1' id='accordion1'><table id='tempTable'><tbody>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> Inner Test1 </td><td> Inner Test2 </td><td> Inner Test3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> N1 </td><td> N2 </td><td> N3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "</tbody></table></div></td></tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody:last').append(nestedrow);


  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 3.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody:last').append(row);

  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 4.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody:last').append(row);
}
```

```css
.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblTest" class="table-awb alternate table table-hover  table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:14px;background-color:#EFF1F1;font-weight:bold;height:25px">
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Please see the picture for more details
[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GabVj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this is that `find('tbody:last')` finds the wrong `tbody`

Here is the working example:

```
<table id="tblTest" class="table-awb alternate table table-hover  table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:14px;background-color:#EFF1F1;font-weight:bold;height:25px">
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="outer"></tbody>
</table>
```

And js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      function LoadTestTable() {
      var row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 1.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody#outer').append(row);

  row = "<tr id='package1' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#OrderPackages' data-target='.packageDetails1'>";
  row += "<td> 2.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.4 </td>";

  row += "</tr>"
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody#outer').append(row);

  var nestedrow = "<tr><td colspan='4' class='hiddenRow'><div class='accordion-body collapse packageDetails1' id='accordion1'><table id='tempTable'><tbody id='inner'>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> Inner Test1 </td><td> Inner Test2 </td><td> Inner Test3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> N1 </td><td> N2 </td><td> N3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "</tbody></table></div></td></tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody#outer').append(nestedrow);


  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 3.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody#outer').append(row);

  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 4.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').find('tbody#outer').append(row);
}

LoadTestTable()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `children` instead of `find` here `$('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(row);`

```js
function LoadTestTable() {
  var row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 1.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 1.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(row);

  row = "<tr id='package1' class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#OrderPackages' data-target='.packageDetails1'>";
  row += "<td> 2.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 2.4 </td>";

  row += "</tr>"
  $('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(row);

  var nestedrow = "<tr><td colspan='4' class='hiddenRow'><div class='accordion-body collapse packageDetails1' id='accordion1'><table id='tempTable'><tbody>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> Inner Test1 </td><td> Inner Test2 </td><td> Inner Test3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "<tr><td> N1 </td><td> N2 </td><td> N3 </td></tr>";
  nestedrow += "</tbody></table></div></td></tr>";
  $('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(nestedrow);


  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 3.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 3.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(row);

  row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td> 4.1 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.2 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.3 </td>";
  row += "<td> 4.4 </td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $('#tblTest').children('tbody:last').append(row);
}
LoadTestTable()
```

```css
.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tblTest" class="table-awb alternate table table-hover  table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:14px;background-color:#EFF1F1;font-weight:bold;height:25px">
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```